# Making Git more secure: How to gen ssh keys in PKCS#8 format with the openssl.exe utility?

Tags: git, ssh

[There is a nice essay](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html) that says the stock "ssh-keygen" creates an older, easier to crack private key, and that PKCS#8 is the way to go.

So, instead of the stock ssh-keygen approach, I want to use a new "ssh-pkcs8-gen" approach.... (not for me, for the git users who hang off my git server).

Everything I have seen discusses taking the ASN.1 output from ssh-keygen and converting it to PKCS#8  This is a lot of steps, and I don't want to make life impossible for my users.

How can I directly, in one step, create a PKCS#8 private key with openssl.exe (or similar tool commonly distributed with Git.... I believe openssl can do it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article "[Improving the security of your SSH private key files](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html)" from [Martin Kleppmann](http://martin.kleppmann.com/contact.html) describes:

- how to generate a classic [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) passphrase-protected key
- how to convert if to PKCS#8 ([Public-Key Cryptography Standards (PKCS) #8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208))

So maybe chaining the two operations together in a script would result in the right key generated in ne step:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N 'super secret passphrase' -f test_rsa_key
mv test_rsa_key test_rsa_key.old
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3 \
    -in test_rsa_key.old -passin 'pass:super secret passphrase' \
    -out test_rsa_key -passout 'pass:super secret passphrase'
```

Comment: Note, on my system, that does work, but throws an error "unable to write random state" -- not sure what that means!

Answer (score 7):

On OpenSSH_8.2p1 it seems that `ssh-keygen` support PKCS8 directly, e.g.:

`ssh-keygen -m PKCS8 -t rsa`